# how to match names whin one group is not present in regex

Tags: python, regex

I am stuck with following regex. my intention is to match following

```
abc_123_v1_f1_t21 
12c_1sdsd_f1_t1 
Android_v1_t21
```

regex i am trying is

```
_(v[1-9]{1,3}\d?_f[1-9]{1,3}\d?_t[1-9]{1,3}\d?)(?!\d)
```

I am not able to get regex match if my names doesn't contains squence (v_f_t).
how to get regex match when i have pattern like **without v or f or t** *ATLEAST two should be present. v_t or f_v or f_t or v_f_t or f_t_v etc*

if I give adcg_f1_t1 it should match

if I give adcg_v2_f1 it should match

if I give adcg_v2_t12 it should match

How to do this ?

Comment: Maybe `(?:(?:_[vft][1-9]{1,3}\d?){1,3})(?!\d)` will do? See https://regex101.com/r/vX7mt7/1

Comment: atleast 2 pattern should be present. I dont watn match for abcd_v1 alone

Comment: Ok, `(?:(?:_[vft][1-9]{1,3}\d?){2,3})(?!\d)`? See https://regex101.com/r/vX7mt7/2

Comment: The outer non-capturing group seems redundant, I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?:_[vft][1-9]{1,3}\d?){2,3}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a9tZPc/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:_[vft][1-9]{1,3}\d?){2,3}` - two or three occurrences of

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[vft]` - `v`/`f`/`t`
  - `[1-9]{1,3}` - one, two or three non-zero digits
  - `\d?` - an optional digit
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The regex, `(?:_[vft]\d{1,3}){2}(?:_[vft]\d{1,3})*` meets your requirement.

- `(?:_[vft]\d{1,3}){2}`: A non-capturing group with occurrence of two times. The group contains an `_` followed by a `v`/`f`/`t` which is in turn followed by one to three digits
- `(?:_[vft]\d{1,3})*`: A non-capturing group with occurrence of zero to unlimited times. The group contains an `_` followed by a`v`/`f`/`t` which is in turn followed by one to three digits

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LozyRv/1)